# Standard textwidth with geometry package

Tags: margins, geometry

I really like the way LaTeX puts text on a4paper (quite large margins), but I need to `\usepackage{geometry}` to change the layout of my appendix. What options should be used with geometry to make everything (textwidth, margins etc) look identical to what it looks like without `\usepackage{geometry}`?

Another way to phrase it would be that I want the same output whether `\usepackage{geometry}` is commented out or uncommented. How is this done?

(I'm rendering PDF's with pdflatex, if that make a difference)

Comment: I don't understand, if you do not want geometry to make changes, don't load it. Why do you just want to change the margins in the apendix?

Comment: The geometry package is not only for changes in the entire document, but can also be handy if you want to do other things, say rotate a page to accommodate for a particularly large figure or set custom text width in particular sections.

Comment: There are packages that deal with rotated material and there are packages that deal with different text widths (although this should be done with care).

Comment: Are they better at it than geometry is?

Comment: Really depends on what you are trying to achieve.